# Is it possible to create mobile app that intercepts and modifies responses

Tags: android, mobile

I am a web developer and i have created a Chrome extension and a social network. They both communicate and the browser extension displays the data.
I would like to make something for mobile devices. I was thinking of making an app and using the web view to inject the data that the extension does on desktop browsers. But i do not think people would download yet another browser...
So, i had an idea to create an app that intercepts responses and modifies the response the same way the browser extension does. That way it does not matter what browser or mobile app is using it, because it would display the modified response...

Is there any way it could be done without hackery?